# reading a file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file named `sqlfile`, with the following content:

```
a.sql
b.sql
c.sql
d.sql
```

What I want is that to store them in variables and then print using `for` loop.
But here I get only `d.sql` in the output of the script.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
files=`echo $line`
done < /home/abdul_old/Desktop/My_Shell_Script/sqlfile

for file in $files
        do
                echo $file
        done
```

Answer (score 6):

A variable can only hold one element, what you want is an *array*

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  files+=( "$line" )
done < /home/abdul_old/Desktop/My_Shell_Script/sqlfile

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while read line
do files="$files $line"
done < /home/abdul_old/Desktop/My_Shell_Script/sqlfile
```

or

```
files=$(</home/abdul_old/Desktop/My_Shell_Script/sqlfile)
```

or

```
files=$(cat /home/abdul_old/Desktop/My_Shell_Script/sqlfile)
```

You're doing way too much work in your loop.

The middle alternative works with `bash`; the other two work with most shells.  Prefer `$(...)` to back-quotes.

This code assumes there are no spaces in file names to mess things up.  If you do use blanks in file names, you have to work marginally harder - see the array-based solution by [SiegeX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207248/siegex)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the "files" as array. otherwise, as soon as the while finishes, "files" stores the latest "line". 
try:

```
files=( "${files[@]}" $line )
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you assifn last value to "files"

You must use for instance += instead of =

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
files+=`echo " $line"`
done < /home/abdul_old/Desktop/My_Shell_Script/sqlfile

for file in $files
        do
                echo $file
        done
```

Comment: You don't need the first `echo`; you could perfectly well use `files+=" $line"` and it would be simpler and more efficient (no subshell).

Comment: @AbdulManaf: are you using `bash`?  Which version of `bash` (find out with `bash --version`).

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I use GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), and += works for me. But the point is  -- you must not reassign the variable. You need to add new value. If += doesn't work for you , you can try for instance   files="$files $line"

Answer (score 0):

Using read is fine but you have to set the IFS environment variable first else leading and trailing white space are removed from each line: [Preserving leading white space while reading>>writing a file line by line in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648055/preserving-leading-white-space-while-readingwriting-a-file-line-by-line-in-bas).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
readarray myData < sqlfile
```

This will put file lines into an array called `myData`
Now you can access any of these lines like this:

```
printf "%s\n" "${myData[0]}" #outputs first line
printf "%s\n" "${myData[2]}" #outputs third line
```

And you can iterate over it:

```
for curLine in "${myData[@]}"; do
    echo "$curLine"
done
```

Note that these lines would contain `\n` character as well. To remove trailing newlines you can use `-t` flag like this:

```
readarray -t myData < sqlfile
```

`readarray` is a synonym to `mapfile`. You can read about it in `man bash`