# Preventing leading spaces from getting ignored using IFS=

Tags: bash, sed, ifs

I am trying to insert few lines before a specific line in an xml file. Though it's working but the formatting is not retained. Leading whitespaces are getting ignored. I know that we have to use IFS= and i also cross-checked it in the following link besides many others but to no avail. :(

Can anyone please point out the mistake i am committing here?

[Preserving leading white space while reading>>writing a file line by line in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648055/preserving-leading-white-space-while-readingwriting-a-file-line-by-line-in-bas)

```
while read line
do
    pattern=keepDependencies
    input_file=/home/john/data_file
    file_to_change="${backup_dir}/"$line"/config.xml"

    while IFS= read -r insert_text
    do
        sed -i "/$pattern/i $insert_text" $file_to_change
    done < "$input_file"
done < days_to_keep_absent
```

Data File:

```
[john ~]$ cat data_file
  <logRotator>
        <daysToKeep>-1</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>5</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
  </logRotator>
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>I&apos;ll clean all the temporary permissions</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
    ...
    ...
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>I&apos;ll clean all the temporary permissions</description>
<logRotator>
<daysToKeep>-1</daysToKeep>
<numToKeep>5</numToKeep>
<artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
<artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
</logRotator>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Could you post config.xml and the actual output?

Comment: Added config.xml and the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `read` which is giving you problems. It's `sed`.

The usual (and, as far as I know, the only Posix-compatible) way of issuing an `i` command is to follow it immediately with a backslash and a newline. The argument consists of the subsequent lines up to the first one not terminated with a backslash:

```
/pattern/i\
    This text is inserted\
So is this text.
```

GNU `sed` allows the inserted text to start on the same line as the `i`, *following any whitespace*. And that is why your whitespace is being deleted.

Try this:

```
while read line
do
  pattern=keepDependencies
  input_file=/home/john/data_file
  # Note: I fixed quoting in the following line.
  file_to_change="$backup_dir/$line/config.xml"

  while IFS= read -r insert_text
  do
    # Note: \\ is reduced to \ because it is inside a double-quoted string
    # The newline is inserted directly. So sed sees i\<newline><inserted text>
    sed -i "/$pattern/i\\
$insert_text" "$file_to_change"
  done < "$input_file"
done < days_to_keep_absent
```

I find that style a little hard to read, so I would usually do something like this:

```
ICMD='i\
'

# ...

sed -i "/$pattern/$ICMD$insert_text" "$file_to_change"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example @rici! It worked like charm. :) This issue was really bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of read (and many other shell's function).

You could work around it: just prepend a char (ex: "|") to the file, and take that out when you output the line

I'll re-use your algorithm without checking it (you say it does do what you need it to, except for missing leading whitespaces) :

The while loop becomes:

```
sed -e 's/^/|/' < "${input_file}" > "${input_file}_modified"
while IFS= read -r insert_text
do
    sed -i "/$pattern/i $( echo "$insert_text" | sed -e 's/^|//' )" $file_to_change
done < "${input_file}_modified"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but there is no difference in output.

Comment: Actually, if you do `IFS= read -r` then you'll get precisely the whitespace you started with.